# Why are Python decorators with arguments syntactically different from those without?

Tags: python, arguments, decorator, callable

[This article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845), linked to a number of times from various stackoverflow questions, describes how decorators with arguments are syntactically different from those without arguments.

- Decorators without arguments: "Notice that `__init__()` is the only method called to perform decoration, and `__call__()` is called every time you call the decorated `sayHello()`."
- Decorators with arguments: "Now the process of decoration calls the constructor and then immediately invokes `__call__()`, which can only take a single argument (the function object) and must return the decorated function object that replaces the original. Notice that `__call__()` is now only invoked once, during decoration, and after that the decorated function that you return from `__call__()` is used for the actual calls."

The explanation given in the article doesn't tell me why the language is set up this way:

> Although this behavior makes sense -- the constructor is now used to capture the decorator arguments, but the object `__call__()` can no longer be used as the decorated function call, so you must instead use `__call__()` to perform the decoration -- it is nonetheless surprising the first time you see it

There are two related features of this setup that are uncomfortable for me:

1. Why provide a way to make no-argument decorators that's not just a special case of the more general method for specifying decorators? And why use `__init__` and `__call__` in both, but have them mean different things?
2. Why use `__call__` in the case of decorators with arguments for a purpose other than calling the decorated function (as the name suggests, at least coming from the no argument case)? Given that `__call__` is only invoked right after `__init__`, why not just pass the function to be decorated as an argument to `__init__` and handle everything that would happen in `__call__` in `__init__` instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because it's the decorator object that's being called in both cases. To make it clearer, given this:

```
def my_decorator(a):
    def wrapper(f):
        def wrapped_function():
            return f() + a
        return wrapped_function
    return wrapper
```

this:

```
@my_decorator(5)
def function():
    return 5
```

is equivalent to this:

```
decorator = my_decorator(5)

@decorator
def function():
    return 5
```

What's happening in the no-argument case is that the decorator gets invoked directly instead of having to return a function that takes the object to be decorated as a parameter.

Comment: In other words, `wrapper` is the decorator, `my_decorator` isn't a decorator, it's a function that _returns_ a decorator (`wrapper` in this case). However it feels natural enough to treat `my_decorator` as a "decorator with arguments"

Comment: Could you check that your code runs? I get "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" when I try to run the decorated function() under Python 2.7.

Comment: I see. The [Bruce Eckel article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808) presents using classes as decoration mechanisms rather than functions, but when it comes to understanding the difference between the args and no-args cases, I think you're right to show functions instead.

Comment: The Pythonic term for what a decorator needs to be is a "callable". Classes are callable, in which case their `__init__` method is invoked. Objects are callable if they have a `__call__` method. This is what's happening in that article. Functions are, by their nature, callable.

Comment: BTW, this answer makes it clear why there's a no-argument version that's not a special case of the with-arguments version: the latter is built on top of the former. I don't see any reason why they had to use the '@' character for both, though.